# Generating Error Graph on Neuroph

Tags: java, neural-network

I'm working on a program and made use of Multilayer Perceptron from Neuroph framework. I looked up in the API documentation of Neuroph to see if it has the method for getting the errors of the network but failed to do so. But I found those methods in another class which is SupervisedLearning. How do I generate an error graph as I train my network (MLP)? I need to at least get the array of errors so I could generate the graph. But there is no such method for MLP.

Comment: You mean that you want the network error in relation to the epochs ("Learning Curve")?

Comment: yes i need to get the errors